no drivers for VMWare virtual network card
I exported a virtualbox VM and imported it to VMware Workstation (also tried Player).
When I started the Windows 10 22H2 VM, I saw that the network card was not installed properly.
I tried to install the VMware-Tools but I still have no drivers for the virtual Windows network interface.
Thanks, very much.

Stop VM, change the network card from menu and start VM

Also make sure to install VMWare tools inside the VM.

I tried this but the VMware Workstation/Player always adds the same type of network interface. When the machine is started, I also tried to reinstall the VMware-tool several times but in the device manager the network interface stys uninstalled.

I use the VMware Workstaion Pro under Linux Mint.
